# iScroll messing up iWebkit framework

Tags: iphone-web-app, iscroll, iwebkit

I am developing a web app using the iWebKit framework. I am trying to have the top bar fixed. So I tried using iScroll. I followed the instructions of iScroll but somehow it is messing up the iWebkit. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need iScroll anymore.

1. Use `position:fixed` on header.
2. Add `overflow:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` to the content div
3. Give the content div a fixed height! 440px in portrait + a 40px top margin (top bar)
4. Do the same for the content div in landscape